# Regex with exception for words

Tags: r, regex, regex-negation

Hi all I'm trying to split a text into sentences and for that, I'm using Regex logic of splitting if there's a blank and a space together.

The text file consists of "Mr.", "U.S." and "U.K." which are the letters upon which I wouldn't like to split the text into sentences.

Regex I'm using can be seen in the image attached
*

This does the job but creates an issue.

[image]

Here the regex is picking up "a. " in the sentence "My name is Mr. Aishwarya. " How can I change it to just pick ". "?

Comment: You should group using parenthesis, and not the square brackets `\b(?:U\.[SK]|Mr)\.` What do you want as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```r
\b(?:Mr|U\.S|U\.K)\.(*SKIP)(*F)|\.\s+
# A shrunk version:
\b(?:Mr|U\.[SK])\.(*SKIP)(*F)|\.\s+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KGBhnh/1). *Details*:

- `\b(?:Mr|U\.S|U\.K)\.(*SKIP)(*F)` - a whole word `Mr.`, `U.S.`, `U.K.` is matched and the match is skipped and the next match is searched for starting from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `\.\s+` - a `.` and then one or more whitespaces.

See an [R demo](https://ideone.com/5z2Wg8):

```r
x <- "My name is Mr. Aishwarya. I live in the U.K. and want to go to U.S. Us will go to Australi. Who else wants to go to U.S.A. ? My wife's name is Ruchika Bhatt. "
strsplit(x, "\\b(?:Mr|U\\.S|U\\.K)\\.(*SKIP)(*F)|\\.\\s+", perl=TRUE)
```

Output:

```r
[[1]]
[1] "My name is Mr. Aishwarya"                                        
[2] "I live in the U.K. and want to go to U.S. Us will go to Australi"
[3] "Who else wants to go to U.S.A"                                   
[4] "? My wife's name is Ruchika Bhatt"
```

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you tried is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^U.S|U.K.|Mr.]` as it starts with `^` and matches any character except for the listed characters.

It can also be written as `[^.US|KMr](\.\s)` and the reason it matches `a.`  because the a is not listed in the character class.

What you want is a grouping mechanism with parenthesis `()` and a pipe `|` to separate the alternatives.

---

Another option is to use a negative lookbehind, to assert not `U.S` `U.K` or `Mr` to the left preceded by a word boundary before matching a dot and a whitespace.

```
(?<!\bU\.[SK]|\bMr)\.\s
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<!` Negative lookbehind, assert what is directly to the left is not

  - `\bU\.[SK]` Match either U.S or U.K
  - `|` Or
  - `\bMr` Match Mr
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\.\s` Match a dot and a whitespace char (or use `\h` to not match a newline, only a space)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/y8hx4X/1)

In R setting perl=TRUE for Perl-compatible regex:

```
strsplit(
    "My name is Mr. Aishwarya. I live in the U.K. and want to go to U.S. Us will go to Australi. Who else wants to go to U.S.A. ? My wife's name is Ruchika Bhatt. ",
    "(?<!\\bU\\.[SK]|\\bMr)\\.\\s",
    perl=TRUE
)
```

Output

```
[[1]]
[1] "My name is Mr. Aishwarya"                                        
[2] "I live in the U.K. and want to go to U.S. Us will go to Australi"
[3] "Who else wants to go to U.S.A"                                   
[4] "? My wife's name is Ruchika Bhatt"
```